# Convert Mat to ImageSource OpenCV for Android

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.forms

With OpenCVSharp, it is very easy to convert a Mat object to `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`.

```
private ImageSource GetImageSource(Mat mat)
{
    return mat.ToWriteableBitmap();
}
```

How can I do this with **Xamarin.OpenCV.Droid**?

How can I convert a Mat to **Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource**?

https://github.com/NAXAM/opencv-android-binding/

**UPDATE**

I resolved this problem in my own by once converting `Mat` to `Bitmap`.

```
var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(mat.Width(), mat.Height(), Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
Utils.MatToBitmap(mat, bitmap);
var src = ImageSource.FromStream(() => getMemoryStream(bitmap));

private static MemoryStream getMemoryStream(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    try
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
        ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return ms;
    }
    catch
    {
        // log etc
        return new MemoryStream();
    }
}
```

Does my code have any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Mat to Stream

```
public Stream MatToStream(Mat mat)
{
    using (var vect = new MatOfByte())
    {
        if (Imgcodecs.Imencode(".png", mat, vect))
            return new MemoryStream(vect.ToArray());
        return Stream.Null;
    }
}
```

Note: There are many `Mat` types (internal structures) so depending upon what your Mat is constructed from, this might not be the most efficient, and it is not taking into consideration the size of the output and what size is needed to most efficiently display the image with the smallest memory consumption.

#### Usage:

```
matImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(MatToStream);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, which helped me a lot. I resolved this problem in my own way by once converting `Mat` to `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`, which does not require a file extension. I'd like you to advise me whether or not my code has any problems. I will show you my code in about 10 hours, since I can't access the repository of my office until then.

Comment: @user4134476 ahh, I totally missed you were looking for an Android specific answer.

Comment: I wrote my code as an update of this article. I'd be happy if you could check it.

Comment: @user4134476 I would not  convert it to a jpg, but use a png to preserve as much quality of the original Mat as possible. Other than that, I alway convert to the size needed for display, so use the destination width/height vs. the orgin's width/height in order to conserve memory and get the best ui performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I try to convert it to png.